# Bloquear iframe no mobile

Tags: html5, css3, iframe, touch

Gostaria de saber se e possível bloquear o scroll de um `<iframe>` de preferencia no mobile pois quando rolo a pagina com o touch da tela o mapa atrapalha segue um trecho do códig

```html
 <iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3655.239544991613!2d-46.73948188533577!3d-23.631590870073904!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce5145592eb1c5%3A0x48114826f8e8c3b5!2sAv.+Giovanni+Gronchi%2C+5930+-+Vila+Andrade%2C+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP%2C+05724-002!5e0!3m2!1spt-PT!2sbr!4v1473358653242"
                        class="iframe" onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'"
                        style="border:0;width: 100%;height: 300px;"></iframe>
```

o.